# How to use an isolated scope property properly?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-watch, controlleras

How to use an isolated scope property properly?

I have a directive, that is called from a page controller, with an attribute `item` passed to it, e.g. `<my-directive item="myItem"></my-directive>`, containing an `id`.

The code below will not work, as it seems like `$scope.item` is undefined in the controller.. like I'm using it too soon. How can I be sure that it is actually set when I want to use it?

```
app.directive('myDirective', [function() {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'template.html',
    scope: {
        item: "="
    },
    controller: ['$scope', 'ExtendedItemFactory', function($scope, ExtendedItemFactory) {
        this.extendedInfo = ExtendedItemFactory.get({ id: $scope.item.id });
    }],
    controllerAs: 'MyDirectiveCtrl'
};
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `$watch` inside your directive that will watch on change in value & will fire the code which you want.

**Code**

```
app.directive('myDirective', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'template.html',
        scope: {
            item: "="
        },
        controller: ['$scope', 'ExtendedItemFactory', function($scope, ExtendedItemFactory) {
            this.extendedInfo = ExtendedItemFactory.get({
                id: $scope.item.id
            });
            $scope.$watch('item', function(newVal, oldVal) {
                if (newVal && newVal != oldVal)
                    this.extendedInfo = ExtendedItemFactory.get({
                        id: $scope.item.id
                    });
            }, true).bind(this);
        }],
        controllerAs: 'MyDirectiveCtrl'
    };
}]);
```

Comment: I have to say that it is strange that angular does not provide a simpler native solution for this.

Comment: @Andreas yes it would work without `.bind(this)` because the we are accessing isolatated scope variable directly..if we wanted to use scope variables of link to the directive controller then only we would use `.bind(this)`.. do up-vote if it does helped you..that..

Answer (score 0):

You're using controllerAs, so you shouldn't need to inject $scope in this instance.

I would change your directive definition to the following, noting the use of bindToController, which will ensure that your isolated scope values are populated and available on your controller:

```
app.directive('myDirective', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'template.html',
        scope: {
            item: "="
        },
        controller: ['ExtendedItemFactory', function(ExtendedItemFactory) {
            this.extendedInfo = ExtendedItemFactory.get({ id: this.item.id });
        }],
        controllerAs: 'MyDirectiveCtrl',
        bindToController: true
    };
}]);
```

Comment: This seems not to work, `item` is not yet defined in the controller when trying your code.

Comment: `<my-directive item="myItem"></my-directive>` where `myItem` is a scope variable on a page controller.

Comment: I've used this pattern loads of times without problems, and I can't immediately see anything wrong from the code snippets shown.  Can you reproduce in a plunker or something?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of initializing `extendedInfo` when the directive loads you could create getter function that retrieves it on demand.

```
this.getExtendedInfo = function(){
    return ExtendedItemFactory.get({ id: $scope.item.id });
}
```

Alternatively you prevent your directive from loading until the `item` is ready

```
<div ng-if="ctrl.item">
    <my-directive item="ctrl.item"></my-directive>
</div>
```

Comment: I must load the information directly on load, so your first suggestion does not work. Your second suggestion is an interesting approach, but it feels wrong to put the logic outside of the directive itself...